# How to execute a .bat file from vboxmanage?

Tags: shell, command-line, virtualbox

I am trying to execute from the host machine (Win 7 64 bit) a simple .bat file in a virtual machine (Win XP 32 bit) under Virtualbox with the following command:

```
C:\Progra~1\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe guestcontrol VXP32bit execute --image C:\Home\start.bat --username admin1
```

And the start.bat file:

```
echo Hello World > hello.txt
```

The order is sent to the VM as an empty terminal is opened but nothing happens and I cannot even write on the terminal.

I tried to convert the .bat in a .exe but the problem is still the same.

What am I doing wrong? Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution, maybe not the best but better than been blocked.
As the bat file is run from outside the VM, the location need to be specified:

```
echo Hello World > c:\Home\hello.txt
```

Or a probably better solution if you need to perform complex stuff in the VM:

```
cd c:\Home
echo Hello World > hello.txt
```